# "Corn Cob Blues" - real story?

Tags: meaning, backstory, john-hartford

There’s a song by John Hartford called "Corn Cob Blues", from a 1967 album.

The song’s about a cowboy singer promoting the wedding of a member of his backing crew, and the thoughts of the groom during the run-up to the ceremony. Presumably the wedding is to be a public ticketed occasion, a bit like one of Hank Williams’ 2nd wedding ceremonies, which was held in the New Orleans Civic Auditorium.

It’s an odd story, and makes for a good quirky song, but does anyone know if there’s a real story behind it? It also mentions "Hurricane Apple", which I think was never a real hurricane.

Comment: Do you mean the album [*Looks at Life*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Looks_at_Life)? According to Wikipedia, it has been released in 1967, not 1966.

Comment: thanks for the correction. I got to know the track via a banjo-playing friend and hadn't checked all the information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The primary source, [John Hartford](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://jonbernsteinwriting.files.wordpress.com/2018/07/hartford-2.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjD7v6a_YbfAhXCcsAKHU5TB4EQFjAUegQIBhAB&usg=AOvVaw1tlHlYD97TbQs9pR2sXq27), belies any notion of the song being based upon true events:

> 'Corn Cob Blues' is about a skinny boy with elopment on his mind who gets involved in a highly commercial wedding venture complete with song and dance routine, stale jokes, and a lot of loud promotion.

There is no record of a storm with the appellation "Hurricane Apple", either within the [.list of current names](https://public.wmo.int/en/About-us/FAQs/faqs-tropical-cyclones/tropical-cyclone-naming) or within the [list of retired hurricane names](https://www.nhc.noaa.gov/aboutnames_history.shtml).

The lyric in question is as follows:

> Well the rain came down and the crowd was slow/
>   And the cowboy hollered and stubbed his toe/
>   The signs on track to see from here to town/
>   Hurricane Apple couldn't knock them down.

At first glance, "Apple" feels as though the songwriter wanted a name comprising of  two syllables with soft consonants to maintain the scan and rhythm.

It is also possible that the name is a call back to the [hurricane which struck New England in 1938](http://www.grouprecipes.com/48159/hurricane-apple-bread-very-old-recipe.html).

Answer (score 0):

It is Hurricane Ethel, not Apple...it was a hurricane that came over the Gulf of Mexico in 1960, so it makes sense that John Hartford would make a reference to a powerful event from his time.